# Deep clone of a class, that has static nested class

Tags: java

I'am doing a task, in short - custom LinkedList. I need to override Object.clone to make deep copy of MyLinkedList, but I don't understand, do I need to clone both, mested and outer class? Here is the code:

```
public class MyLinkedList implements Cloneable {

    private Entry header;
    private int size;

    .....................

    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        MyLinkedList newObject = null;
        try {
            newObject = (MyLinkedList) super.clone();
            newObject.header = this.header.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            System.err.print("Clone not supported");
        }
        return newObject;
    }

    private static class Entry implements Cloneable {
        double data;
        Entry prev;
        Entry next;

        public Entry(double data, Entry next, Entry prev) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
            this.prev = prev;    
        }

        @Override
        public Entry clone() {
            Entry newObject = null;
            try {
                newObject = (Entry) super.clone();
                newObject.prev = this.prev.clone();
                newObject.next = this.next.clone();
            } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
                System.err.print("Clone not supported");
            }
            return newObject;
        }
    }   
}
```

When i try to clone MyLinkedList i get java.lang.StackOverflowError. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not a deep copy; you aren't cloning the data.

Comment: 'Static inner' is a contradiction in terms: see JLS #8.1.3. This is a static nested class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you clone a node, you also clone both of its adjacent nodes.

Each of those nodes proceeds to clone *their* adjacent nodes, thus cloning the original node again.

(actually, it clones the previous node first, and races around the double-linked list, and never touches `next`)

As you fix that, make sure that the clone's `next.previous` refers to the original clone.

Comment: Can you give me a little hint please, which Override method needs to be changed? First, second, both? I understand the problem, but can't figure out how to stop recursive cloning.

Comment: @Konstantin: The problem is in `Entry.clone()`.  You need to somehow detect when you've gone all the way around the tree and reuse the original first node.  You probably shouldn't call `super.clone()` at all.

Comment: In fact, it would be much easier to not make `Entry` cloneable, and instead clone every entry in a loop in `MyLinkedList.clone()`.